# Получить массив со значениями атрибута href

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь получить массив href с этой страницы http://vm1.culture.ru/abramtsevo/catalog, но вот так не выходит:

```
$('.catalog__body__items .catalog__body__items__item__image').find('a[href]').each(function() {
    hrefs.push($(this).attr('href'));
})
```

и так не выходит:

```
$('.catalog__body__items .catalog__body__items__item__image').find('a[href]').each(function() {
    hrefs.push(this.href);
})
```

Лишь получаю массив с тегами a (с атрибутами).

Comment: Попробуйте в find указать просто (a) вы же потом в цикле всеравно вытаскиваете href у них

Comment: @quaresma89, так вовсе пустой массив приходит.

Comment: _Лишь получаю массив с тегами a (с атрибутами)._ - где получаешь? как проверяешь?

Comment: В консоли на указанной странице.

Comment: _В консоли на указанной странице_ - что именно ты проверяешь и **как**?

Comment: Моя ошибка, все было правильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо прохода `each` в данном случае можно использовать [метод `map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) с последующим вызовом [метода get](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get2)

```
var hrefs = $('.catalog__body__items .catalog__body__items__item__image')
    .find('a[href]')
    .map(function() { return this.href; })
    .get();
```

В результате в `hrefs` будет массив значений атрибутов.

При этом подходе не будет неоднозначности где результат обработки, а где результат выборки элементов.

Comment: Очень хорошая реализация!

Answer (score 2):

`$('.catalog__body__items__item__image .catalog__body__items__item__name')` а если такой селектор?

```
$('.catalog__body__items__item__image .catalog__body__items__item__name').each(function(){
console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Вот так у меня выдает в консоли href всех 9-ти ссылок,не знаю что у вас не так там.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот даже скриншот вам показываю.

Comment: Тот же результат.

Comment: Не может быть,я запустил у меня нашло 9 ссылок

Comment: А можно полный запрос, который можно ввести консоли, чтобы сразу проверить?

Comment: Я поправил ответ с кодом.Проверяйте

Comment: https://pp.vk.me/c837331/v837331797/47c4/iNPw6rZkObU.jpg - а что массив внизу значит?

Comment: Показывает элементы найденные по селектору.Ваша задача решилась или опять что то не так?)

Comment: Ах, выходит, и мои варианты давали нужный результат... Ладно, все равно спасибо!